# how to upload picture input from streamlit app to cloud

Tags: python, streamlit

i am doing a face registration & recognition project on streamlit but i get stucked in face registration step because i can't upload the input picture data to the cloud (esp deta)

```
import streamlit as st
imgs = st.camera_input('Take a picture')
if imgs is not None:
    img = st.image(imgs)
```

can anyone help me? Thanks so much

i've tried many ways, from adding a `st.download_button` to using method in this document https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.camera_input but still get errors

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't [enabled camera access for your browser](https://docs.streamlit.io/knowledge-base/using-streamlit/enable-camera). In Chrome, you can do this via Settings > Privacy and security > Site settings > Camera.